# How to query- Where In Array Key Value Laravel with Mongodb

Tags: laravel, mongodb, laravel-6.2

This is my database Structure

```
{ 
    "_id":"5e4d4d6fc01c0000cc0009bd",
    "UID":"5e30376327050000b3006cde",
    "delevery_charge":25,
    "order_item":[ 
        { 
            "id":"5e2f4a636c630000f20053bc",
            "Name":"XXXXX",
            "info":"5e26098d94500000870044ac",
        }
    ],
    "subtotal":110,
    "status":1,
    "updated_at":"2020-02-19T14:59:59.000Z",
    "created_at":"2020-02-19T14:59:59.000Z"
}
```

I want to Find data where `order_item=>info` ID .. Im using Mongo db

```
$db = Table::where(''Dont Know what to do)->first();
```

How can I do that ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the [$elemMatch documentation in MongoDB](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/)

`db.orders.find({ "order_item" : { "$elemMatch" : { "info" : "5e26098d94500000870044ac" } } });`

Should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

For Laravel you can use the following query:

```
$info = "5e26098d94500000870044ac";
$result = Table::where('order_item', 'elemMatch', ['info'=>$info])->get()->first();
```

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure about mongoDB,but you can use json where clauses.

Laravel also supports querying JSON column types on databases that provide support for JSON column types. Currently, this includes MySQL 5.7 and PostgreSQL. To query a JSON column, use the -> operator:

```
$result = Table::where('order_item->info', 'SOME VALUE')->get();
```